# Large deviation of sum of Gaussian variables

Tags: pr.probability, gaussian

Let $X_i$ is $N(b_i,b_i^2)$, where $0<b_i\leq \alpha$. The $X_i$ are independent, but not identical (i.e. $b_i$ are not all equal). We concern the upper bound of the tail probability $P(|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i-\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)|\geq t)$, i.e.

\begin{equation}
P(|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i-\sum_{i=1}^nb_i|\geq t)\leq \textit{UB}
\end{equation}

From the commonly-used gaussian tail bound (namely, if $g$ is $N(0,1)$, then $P(|g|\geq t)\leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}t}\exp(-\frac{t^2}{2})$), we obtain

$$P(|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i-\sum_{i=1}^nb_i|\geq t)\leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}t}\exp(-\frac{t^2}{2 \sum b_i^2})\leq\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}t}\exp(-\frac{t^2}{2 n\alpha^2})$$
where the last inequality holds since $b_i\leq \alpha$ by assumption.

However, this bound does not suit my purpose, since there is a $n$ in the denominator, which will weaken the decay of the tail, when $n$ grows. Thus I have the following quesitons:

(1) Is this bound tight when $t>\sum_{i=1}^n b_i$?

(2) I learned from [downside page 38](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf) that the tail probability of sum of sub-exponential random variables $x_i$ is $P(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{\sqrt{n}}\geq t)\leq 2\exp(-t\sqrt{n})$ in the large deviation regime ($t>C\sqrt{n}$). Equivalently, $$P(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i \geq t)\leq 2\exp(-t)$$ in the large deviation regime (*$t>C\sqrt{n}$*) (**corrected to $t>Cn$**) , for sub-exponential variables $x_i$.

This tail bound has no factor of $n$ which fits what I want in my case (I want the upper bound $\textit{UB}$ to be in the form of $\exp(-t\cdot n^\beta)$ where $\beta\geq 0$). Thus I am wondering whether I can also have this type of tail (where $n$ is on the numerator) in my case?

Comment: Are the $X_i$ i.i.d.? If yes, I missed it or it needs to be stated

Comment: @kodlu $X_i$ independent but not identical. I re-edited the post. Thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 2):

1.yes the bound is tight because sum of ind Gaussians is just another Gaussian, and for tail of the Gaussian we have tight approximations $P[X>x]\approx \tfrac16e^{-x^2} + \tfrac12e^{-\frac43 x^2}$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function.

2.actualy what you wrote is not quite correct. From pg 38: you have

$$P(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i \geq \tilde{t})\leq 2\exp(-\tilde{t}),$$

in the large deviation regime $(\tilde{t}>CN)$, because of the change of variables $\tilde{t}=t\sqrt{N}$.

Generally even for bounded variables $[a_{i},b_{i}]$ from the generally sharp [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality), you have the presence of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i-a_i$.

If don't like $n$ in the bound, how about just having the variances $b_i$ decay so that

$$\sum b_{i}^{2}<C?$$

answer to comments: The sum of those Gaussians has variance $\sigma^{2}=\sum b_{i}^{2}$ and so

$$P[|X-E[X]|>t]\leq exp(-\frac{t^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}).$$

Now if we want to remove $\sigma^{2}$, we can do the change of variables $\tilde{t}=\frac{t}{\sigma}$ to get

$$P[|X-E[X]|>\tilde{t}\sigma]\leq exp(-\frac{\tilde{t^{2}}}{2}).$$

That means that if $R\geq \tilde{t}\sigma$ we get

$$P[|X-E[X]|>R]\leq exp(-\frac{\tilde{t^{2}}}{2}).$$

If we are ok with a cost of having $t$ instead of $t^{2}$, then let $R:=\tilde{t}\sigma$. Then we have for $\tilde{t}>\sigma$

$\tilde{t}^{2}>\tilde{t}\sigma=R$ and so

$$P[|X-E[X]|>R]\leq exp(-\frac{\tilde{t^{2}}}{2})\leq exp(-\frac{R}{2}).$$

Generally

$$P[|X-E[X]|>R]\leq  exp(-\frac{R}{2}),$$

for $R\geq \sigma^{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to write up! Could I have follow-up questions? I am still confused. For question 1: where could I see that this bound is tight in the regime of $t>\sum_{i=1}^n b_i$. I am particular interested in this regime, other than for all $t>0$.

Comment: For question 2: Yes I made a simple mistake, the new variable $t^~$ is $>Cn$. I corrected in the post. Moreover, for the sub-exponential variables whose tails are heavier than Gaussian, it summation has light tail in large deviation regime in the sense that its tail bound $2\exp(-t^~)$ has no factor of $n$ in the denominator. For summation of Gaussian, can we have something similar in this regime?

Comment: in q1, the approximation for the error function gets better with large t , so no.

Comment: for q2, yes and you already wrote it, so you will have $t>c \sqrt{\sum b_{i}^{2}}$ if do the change of variables. So to avoid n all together, your best hope is to have $\sqrt{\sum^{n} b_{i}^{2}}$ grow slower than $n$.

Comment: sorry I cannot follow the q2. I can only obtain that when $t>c\sum b_i^2$, the tail bound is less than $2\exp(-ct)$ in the Gaussian case, see: consider the gaussian $X_i$ in the post, $P(|\sum X_i-E(\sum X_i)\geq t)\leq 2\exp(-\frac{t^2}{2\sum b_i^2})$, then since $t>c\sum b_i^2$ then this is further $\leq 2\exp(-\frac{t c\sum b_i^2}{2\sum b_i^2})=2\exp(-ct)$.

Comment: ok.. So let $t^\sim=t\sqrt{\sum b_i^2}$, then $P(|\sum X_i-E(\sum X_i)\geq t)$ becomes $P(|\sum X_i-E(\sum X_i)\geq \frac{t^\sim}{\sqrt{\sum b_i^2}})$, and $2\exp(-\frac{t^2}{2\sum b_i^2})$ becomes $2\exp(-\frac{(t^\sim)^2}{2(\sum b_i^2)^2})$?

Comment: @chloe ok i updated the answer.

Comment: ah thanks! Now I get it. But I feel that I don't understand the difference between (1) $>t$ for $\forall t>0$, and (2) $>t\sqrt{\sum b_i^2}$ for $\forall t>0$. This two are equivalent right?

Comment: do you mean $>\tilde{t}\sqrt{\sum b^2}$ for all $\tilde{t}>0$? if so yes due to the change of variables.

Comment: Sorry. Forget my previous comment. But I still think this is different from the bound for sum of sub-exponential rvs. For simplicity and to be consistent to your update content, I will just write $X$ to denote sum of $X_i$ and $\sigma$ to denote the $\sqrt{n}$. In the case of sub-exp, we have $P(|\frac{X}{\sigma}|\geq t)\leq 2\exp{(-t\sigma)}$ and this is equivalent to $P(|X|\geq t)\leq 2\exp(-t)$. Did you see the difference from gaussian case?

Comment: In this case the $\sigma$ can be gone, but in gaussian case, $\sigma$ is still there. If we don't like $\sigma$ to be in the right handside then we remove it to the left side as $P(\cdots\geq \sigma t)$ or $P(\frac{X}{\sigma}\geq \cdots)$. But in any way, it is still there.

Comment: I hope I clarify my question well.. thank you!

Comment: What I liked about the bound of sum of sub-exp rvs when $t>cn$ is that: there is $\sqrt{n}$ on the nominator so that we can actually remove it from the inequality by change of variable, if we are fine to sacrifice $t>c\sqrt{n}$ to larger value $t>cn$.

Comment: @chloe I updated. So you could have something analogous but it will cost to be $e^{-t}$ rather than $e^{-t^{2}}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I am interested in the case of $t>c\sqrt{n}$, instead of $t>\sum b_i^2$. But I think then I would need to know which one is larger?

Comment: well, yeah it depends on the choice of $b_i$.